# JPA - using long array in IN operator throws cast exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

am new to JPA and am able to get it quickly, I had been trying a select query using "IN" operator in the query and had been getting the error as down. What I do is, i get a array of (long) message ids from a function and i use it to select the record based on those ids. Here is my query

```
select t from MessageTable t where t.messageId IN (:id)  
query.setParameter("id", id);
```

I had just shown you part of the code, in entity messageId is long and in Oracle DB its number. When i try as just as long variable it works, it doesn't seem to work when i pass long array. Had any one come across such a problem can some one help out. This is the error

> 14:24:49,428 INFO [LongType] could not bind value '[J@14f76da' to
>   parameter: 1; [J cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays `Long[]` and `long[]` are not valid types of arguments for IN when you want to check against long/Long - only following are:

- `Long`
- `long` and
- `Collection<Long>` (collection_valued_input_parameter)

If you want to stick with JPA and not use [org.Hibernate.Query.setParameterList](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29) suggested by Kshitij, you have to convert your argument to `Collections<Long>`.

Conversion is easily done, either by rolling your own or for example with help of [ArrayUtil](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28long%5B%5D%29):

```
long[] id = {1L, 2L};
Long[] longs = ArrayUtils.toObject(id);
Collection<Long> list = Arrays.asList(longs);
```

Comment: The API allows you to pass Collection<T>, so it will work with Set<Long> and other Collection subtypes, not just List<Long>

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
query.setParameterList("id", ids);
```

Comment: Thanks, I Had to as it as List.