# syntax error at or near $1 and also some exception sql grammar exception

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

I'm getting an error syntax error at or near $1 and also some exception sql grammar exception

```
"select t1.* from ( select * from employee_additional_attributes  where stwid in :stwIdList )"
            + "as t1 join ( select stwid, max(employee_additional_attribute_id) as employee_additional_attribute_id from employee_additional_attributes"
            + "where stwid in :stwIdList and mis_attribute_id in (:attributeId) and start_time <= date(:date) group by stwid )"
            + "as t2 using ( stwid, employee_additional_attribute_id" )
```

Comment: can you add the exceptions to your question please

Comment: Please add the whole exceptions.

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: @RameshKumar, update your question and add complete java exception stacktrace

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL use the `$<n>` syntax for placeholders in parameterized queries (such as prepared statements in the underlying connection).

You have a syntax error in your first (`$1`) parameter:
(and of course some white-space syntax errors, which @Jens mentioned)

```
where stwid in :stwIdList
```

The right syntax for `IN` is `<expression> IN (<expression>, ...)`. You cannot bind multiple values with a single parameter (with JDBC). If you can bind an array, you could use the `<expression> = ANY (<array-expression>)` syntax.

For hibernate see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682735/jpa-using-long-array-in-in-operator-throws-cast-exception) (note the parenthesis around the query parameter).

Comment: ya thanks can you write in my query and send it to me please @pozs

Comment: @RameshKumar If you use hibernate, it just needs parenthesis around the parameter, after every `IN`. This is wrong: `stwid in :stwIdList`; this should work: `mis_attribute_id in (:attributeId)` (both are from your query)